# css display flex alignment issue

Tags: html, css

i have created a sort of calendar to manage events inside school rooms, in each day/room i try to manage it by using flex but it cause problem of alignment.
The goal is to place side by side the event with same time range and to place vertically the events with different time range. In my code everything is aligned side by side.
Here my code:

```
<div style="position:relative; display:flex;" id="15_2023_1_20">
    <div style="margin: 16px 1px 0px; height: 48px; flex: 1 1 0%; background-color: rgb(221, 126, 107); color: rgb(102, 102, 102); border-radius: 3px; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px 5px; cursor: pointer;" class="mod-lezione c340 d35970" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-id="340" data-cal-id="112880" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="Recitazione 04/22<br>Teacher 1<br>09:00 - 12:00"><span>Recitazione 04/22<br>Teacher 1<br></span></div>
    <div style="margin: 128px 1px 0px; height: 48px; flex: 1 1 0%; background-color: rgb(230, 145, 56); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-radius: 3px; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px 5px; cursor: pointer;" class="mod-lezione c407 d35989" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-id="407" data-cal-id="132084" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="Event Manager Nov 2022<br>Teacher 2<br>16:00 - 19:00"><span>Event Manager Nov 2022<br>Teacher 2<br></span></div>
    <div style="margin: 64px 1px 0px; height: 48px; flex: 1 1 0%; background-color: rgb(221, 126, 107); color: rgb(102, 102, 102); border-radius: 3px; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px 5px; cursor: pointer;" class="mod-lezione c340 d35971" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-id="340" data-cal-id="141507" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="Recitazione 04/22<br>Teacher 3<br>12:00 - 15:00"><span>Recitazione 04/22<br>Teacher 3<br></span></div>
</div>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: I think you'll need JavaScript to achive this, since this is supposably dynamic ?

Comment: what do you mean with same time range? i see different times

Comment: @johan it think so but i don't know how to achieve it. the real example is Google Calendar how it manage events. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful for you to try this code

```html
<div style="position:relative; display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap; gap: 15px;" id="15_2023_1_20">
  <div style="height: 48px; min-width: 20%; flex: 1 1 0%; background-color: rgb(221, 126, 107); color: rgb(102, 102, 102); border-radius: 3px; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px 5px; cursor: pointer;" class="mod-lezione c340 d35970" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-id="340" data-cal-id="112880" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="Recitazione 04/22<br>Teacher 1<br>09:00 - 12:00"><span>Recitazione 04/22<br>Teacher 1<br></span></div>
  <div style="height: 48px; min-width: 20%; flex: 1 1 0%; background-color: rgb(230, 145, 56); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-radius: 3px; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px 5px; cursor: pointer;" class="mod-lezione c407 d35989" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-id="407" data-cal-id="132084" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="Event Manager Nov 2022<br>Teacher 2<br>16:00 - 19:00"><span>Event Manager Nov 2022<br>Teacher 2<br></span></div>
  <div style="height: 48px; min-width: 20%; flex: 1 1 0%; background-color: rgb(221, 126, 107); color: rgb(102, 102, 102); border-radius: 3px; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px 5px; cursor: pointer;" class="mod-lezione c340 d35971" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-id="340" data-cal-id="141507" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="Recitazione 04/22<br>Teacher 3<br>12:00 - 15:00"><span>Recitazione 04/22<br>Teacher 3<br></span></div>
  <div style="height: 48px; min-width: 20%; flex: 1 1 0%; background-color: rgb(230, 145, 56); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-radius: 3px; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px 5px; cursor: pointer;" class="mod-lezione c407 d35989" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-id="407" data-cal-id="132084" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="Event Manager Nov 2022<br>Teacher 2<br>16:00 - 19:00"><span>Event Manager Nov 2022<br>Teacher 2<br></span></div>
  <div style="height: 48px; min-width: 20%; flex: 1 1 0%; background-color: rgb(221, 126, 107); color: rgb(102, 102, 102); border-radius: 3px; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px 5px; cursor: pointer;" class="mod-lezione c340 d35971" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-id="340" data-cal-id="141507" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="Recitazione 04/22<br>Teacher 3<br>12:00 - 15:00"><span>Recitazione 04/22<br>Teacher 3<br></span></div>
  <div style="height: 48px; min-width: 20%; flex: 1 1 0%; background-color: rgb(221, 126, 107); color: rgb(102, 102, 102); border-radius: 3px; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px 5px; cursor: pointer;" class="mod-lezione c340 d35971" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-id="340" data-cal-id="141507" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="Recitazione 04/22<br>Teacher 3<br>12:00 - 15:00"><span>Recitazione 04/22<br>Teacher 3<br></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks Vinod but your code don't take in consideration the time of the events, on the example i post the events had to be aligned vertically in column why there is not two or more events in the same time. a real example of how may work is Google Calendar. thanks